# iPhone4, UIWebView and HTML5

Tags: html, uiwebview, ios4, websocket

is there any list which HTML5 features the UIWebView supports and which not? I am interested mainly in:

1) localStorage/sessionStorage

2) offline manifest

3) web sockets

4) web workers

In pre-iOS4 there was not an offline manifest support, which was necessary to program in objective-C, which - when done broke the localStorage support, since the UIWebView does not allow sharing localStorage content between pages accessed online and pages manually downloaded and stored in the file system, because the URL was different

Thanks a lot
BR
STeN

Answer (score 0):

The right answer ought to be caniuse.com which is currently the best site for non-mobile browser info. From what I've found there is no other site which has this sort of information. I would encourage you to encourage the maintainer of caniuse.com to add mobile browser information. You can do that by posting here:

http://a.deveria.com/?p=82#comments

Comment: Hi, it would be great, if there will be some page focusing on mobile web browsers for Symbian,Android, iPhone and Blackberry and also page focusing on wrapper components on those mobile phones like UIWebView on iPhone, webkit.WebView on Android, QWebView on Symbian Qt and BrowserField2 on Blackberry. I am mobile phone developer, who is doing also hybrid native/HTML5 applications and knowing the level of mobile support for HTML5, CSS3 features will help me a lot! I am open to help creator of such a page.
BR